# Testing a Doctrine2 Entity with assertEquals results in fatal out-of-memory error

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I have a PHPUnit test that's using a Doctrine2 custom repository and Doctrine Fixtures. I wanted to test that a query gave me back an expected entity from my fixture.

But when I try `$this->assertEquals($expectedEntity, $result);`, I get `Fatal error: out of memory`. I'm guessing it is recursing into all the relations and the entity manager and whatnot.

Is there a good way to test this equality? Should I just assertEquals on the IDs of the entities?

**Edit:**
Here is the test code

```
<?php
use Liip\FunctionalTestBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class AbstractRepositoryTestCase extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository 
     */
    protected $repo;

    /**
     * @var Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\AbstractExecutor
     */
    protected $fixtureExecutor;

    /**
     * @var string Which repository to load, overriden by derived class
     */
    protected $repoName;

    /**
     * @var array Fixture classes to load on setup
     */
    protected $fixtures = array();

    public function setUp()
    {
        $kernel = static::createKernel();
        $this->repo = $kernel->boot();
        $this->repo = $kernel->getContainer()
                             ->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')
                             ->getRepository($this->repoName);

        $this->fixtureExecutor = $this->loadFixtures($this->getFixtures());
    }

    public function getFixtures()
    {
        return $this->fixtures;
    }
}

class ArticleRepositoryTest extends AbstractRepositoryTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var string Which repository to load, overriden by derived class
     */
    protected $repoName = 'MyMainBundle:Article';

    /**
     * @var array Fixture classes to load on setup
     */
    protected $fixtures = array(
        'My\MainBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadUserData',
        'My\MainBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadArticleData',
        'My\MainBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadFeedsData',
        'My\MainBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadFeedDataData',
        'My\MainBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadUserReadArticleData',
    );
    public function testGetNextArticle_ExpectCorrect()
    {
        /** @var Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\ReferenceRepository **/
        $refRepo = $this->fixtureExecutor->getReferenceRepository();

        /** @var FeedStream\MainBundle\Entity\Article **/
        $curr = $refRepo->getReference('feed-1-article-3');
        $expected = $refRepo->getReference('feed-1-article-2');
        $expected2 = $refRepo->getReference('feed-1-article-1');
        $next = $this->repo->getNextArticle($curr->getFeed()->getId(), $curr);

        $this->assertNotNull($next);
        // this is the part that doesn't work
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $next);
        // this is the code I've used instead
        $this->assertEquals($expected->getId(), $next->getId());
    }
}
```

Here is the entity (getters/setters omitted to save space)

```
<?php

namespace My\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * My\MainBundle\Entity\Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles", uniqueConstraints={
 *   @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="feed_guid", columns={"feed_id", "guid"}),
 *   @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="article_slug_unique", columns={"feed_id", "slug"})
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="My\MainBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $guid
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="guid", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $guid;

    /**
     * @var string $title
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var datetime $pubDate
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pub_date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $pubDate;

    /**
     * @var text $summary
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="summary", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $summary;

    /**
     * @var text $content
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var string $sourceUrl
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="source_url", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $sourceUrl;

    /**
     * @var string $commentUrl
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="comment_url", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $commentUrl;

    /**
     * @var string $slug
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @var string $thumbnailFile
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="thumbnail_file", type="string", length=64, nullable=true)
     */
    private $thumbnailFile;

    /**
     * @var My\MainBundle\Entity\ArticleEnclosure
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="My\MainBundle\Entity\ArticleEnclosure")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="thumbnail_enclosure_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $thumbnailEnclosure;

    /**
     * @var My\MainBundle\Entity\ArticleImageScrape
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="My\MainBundle\Entity\ArticleImageScrape")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="thumbnail_scrape_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=false)
     * })
     */
    private $thumbnailScrape;

    /**
     * @var My\MainBundle\Entity\ArticleBitly
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="My\MainBundle\Entity\ArticleBitly", mappedBy="article", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $bitly;

    /**
     * @var My\MainBundle\Entity\ArticleEnclosure
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="My\MainBundle\Entity\ArticleEnclosure", mappedBy="article", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $enclosures;

    /**
     * @var My\MainBundle\Entity\ArticleImageScrape
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="My\MainBundle\Entity\ArticleImageScrape", mappedBy="article", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $scrapes;

    /**
     * @var My\MainBundle\Entity\ArticleLink
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="My\MainBundle\Entity\ArticleLink", mappedBy="article", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $links;

    /**
     * @var My\MainBundle\Entity\Feed
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="My\MainBundle\Entity\Feed", inversedBy="articles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="feed_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * })
     */
    private $feed;

    /**
     * @var My\MainBundle\Entity\ArticleAuthor
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="My\MainBundle\Entity\ArticleAuthor", inversedBy="articles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $author;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->links = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code (like the entity) and the test? Entities in doctrine2 have no connection to the entity manager, so you either do something wrong or something is broken!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also test the class in addition to the ID.

Comment: Thanks I guess that makes sense since any other entity type would also have `getId()`

Comment: You can also use === to test the equality on the object references, instead of == which does a comparison of objects properties. In theory, it should work because Doctrine use an identity map, but I'm not sure this map is used in all circonstances.

Comment: Interesting. I wouldn't have thought that the references would be the same from the Fixture reference and the query result, but as you said it may be.